# How to get registered service by its concrete type instead of its interface type?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

Please suppose I have the following classes and interfaces:

```
public class ConcreteRepository : IRepository<T>, IEntityOwner
{ }

public interface IRepository<T>
{ }

public interface IEntityOwner
{ }

public class SomeModel
{ }
```

and suppose I have registered the following service in my Asp.Net Core 2.0 startup class:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository<SomeModel>, ConcreteRepository>();
```

I can get the instance of ConcreteRepository like this:

```
var concreteRepositoryInstance = 
         httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IRepository<SomeModel>))
              as IRepository<SomeModel>;
```

**How can I get the instance of ConcreteRepository by the type of ConcreteRepository?**

I imagine something like this:

```
var concreteRepositoryInstance =  
         httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ConcreteRepository))
              as IEntityOwner;
```

Please note that I cannot use any generics to answer my question, because my use case refers to a custom attribute that takes the type of concreteRepository as an input parameter (and attributes cannot be generics by design).

What I tried so far:

(a) I checked and tried all `httpContext.RequestServices.GetService...` methods but they all require the type of interface with which the concrete type is registered with.

(b) I was thinking about getting *all* services from the dependency container, but IServiceProvider does not offer getting *all* services. I can only get them by the type of interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try registering type directly like so

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // container will create the instance of this type
    services.AddScoped<ConcreteRepository>();
}
```

Then you will be able to resolve type directly with

```
var concreteRepositoryInstance =  
         httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ConcreteRepository))
              as IEntityOwner;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I also added all self registered repositories with a one liner to the startup class: `services.Scan(scan => scan).FromAssemblyOf<ConcreteRepository>().AddClasses().AsSelf().WithScopedLifetime());`